# Jenkins: refused to connect

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'll try to solve the following issue:

I work with Jenkins server, all was fine early...
But today I did execute a `sudo yum update` command on the jenkins server. After that I get the error `refused to connect.` when I try to get the jenkins with browser.

[image]

I try to re-up the docker container:

```
docker-compose -f grid.yml down -v
docker-compose -f grid.yml up -d
```

But I have the error

```
docker: Can't start service <name> unable to find "pids" in controller set: unknown.
```

Screenshot:
[image]

---

So, I execute `check-config.sh` script, as suggested by @Brian Walker, and get the following result:

```
- cgroup hierarchy: properly mounted [/cgroup]
- CONFIG_NAMESPACES: enabled
- CONFIG_NET_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_PID_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_IPC_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_UTS_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUPS: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED: enabled
- CONFIG_CPUSETS: enabled
- CONFIG_MEMCG: enabled
- CONFIG_KEYS: enabled
- CONFIG_VETH: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_BRIDGE: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_BRIDGE_NETFILTER: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NF_NAT_IPV4: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ADDRTYPE: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPVS: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NF_NAT: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NF_NAT_NEEDED: enabled
- CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE: enabled

Optional Features:
- CONFIG_USER_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_SECCOMP: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS: enabled
- CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP: enabled
- CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP_ENABLED: enabled
- CONFIG_LEGACY_VSYSCALL_EMULATE: enabled
- CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP: enabled
- CONFIG_BLK_DEV_THROTTLING: enabled
- CONFIG_IOSCHED_CFQ: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_CFQ_GROUP_IOSCHED: missing
- CONFIG_CGROUP_PERF: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_HUGETLB: enabled
- CONFIG_NET_CLS_CGROUP: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_CGROUP_NET_PRIO: enabled
- CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH: enabled
- CONFIG_FAIR_GROUP_SCHED: enabled
- CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED: enabled
- CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REDIRECT: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_VS: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_VS_NFCT: enabled
- CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_TCP: enabled
- CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_UDP: enabled
- CONFIG_IP_VS_RR: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_EXT3_FS: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_EXT3_FS_XATTR: missing
- CONFIG_EXT3_FS_POSIX_ACL: enabled
- CONFIG_EXT3_FS_SECURITY: enabled
    (enable these ext3 configs if you are using ext3 as backing filesystem)
- CONFIG_EXT4_FS: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_EXT4_FS_POSIX_ACL: enabled
- CONFIG_EXT4_FS_SECURITY: enabled
- Network Drivers:
  - "overlay":
    - CONFIG_VXLAN: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_BRIDGE_VLAN_FILTERING: enabled
      Optional (for encrypted networks):
      - CONFIG_CRYPTO: enabled
      - CONFIG_CRYPTO_AEAD: enabled (as module)
      - CONFIG_CRYPTO_GCM: enabled (as module)
      - CONFIG_CRYPTO_SEQIV: enabled (as module)
      - CONFIG_CRYPTO_GHASH: enabled (as module)
      - CONFIG_XFRM: enabled
      - CONFIG_XFRM_USER: enabled (as module)
      - CONFIG_XFRM_ALGO: enabled (as module)
      - CONFIG_INET_ESP: enabled (as module)
      - CONFIG_INET_XFRM_MODE_TRANSPORT: enabled (as module)
  - "ipvlan":
    - CONFIG_IPVLAN: missing
  - "macvlan":
    - CONFIG_MACVLAN: missing
    - CONFIG_DUMMY: enabled (as module)
  - "ftp,tftp client in container":
    - CONFIG_NF_NAT_FTP: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_NF_NAT_TFTP: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TFTP: enabled (as module)
- Storage Drivers:
  - "aufs":
    - CONFIG_AUFS_FS: missing
  - "btrfs":
    - CONFIG_BTRFS_FS: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_BTRFS_FS_POSIX_ACL: enabled
  - "devicemapper":
    - CONFIG_BLK_DEV_DM: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_DM_THIN_PROVISIONING: enabled (as module)
  - "overlay":
    - CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS: enabled (as module)
  - "zfs":
    - /dev/zfs: missing
    - zfs command: missing
    - zpool command: missing
```

I do not know if these issues are bound. But that's all that I have from documentation and also I haven't DevOps in our team. Can Anyone help me?

Comment: Check your Docker version is supported on the OS you are running. May need to update OS and/or Docker to match. This issue shows the same error: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37924

Answer (score 0):

I made the decisions to cancel the `yum update` command and everything works well now:https://access.redhat.com/solutions/64069